# JAVA EE proxy pattern

Tags: dependency-injection, jakarta-ee, cdi, proxy-pattern

I keep reading everywhere that when you ask for dependencies to be injected in a bean, you are injected a proxy to an instance of that resource. I believe I know what a proxy is, its an instance that knows how to forward messages to another instance. It's also stated that it is this pattern that allows the container to provide services to this managed beans.

I don't understand this quite well. Why is a proxy necessary? And how is this implemented? is there a proxy object for each bean? or do i have many proxies forwarding to one instance? or maybe neither?

Also, from the book design patterns from the GoF, I've read that you have to provide a proxy class that acts as a placeholder. But I never do that in Java EE, does the application server create proxy class during runtime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The essential assumption behind the proxy pattern is that you should not have to care about it from a "user" point of view. The proxy masquerades as the declared type and should behave the same way. The added value comes from what the proxy does before or after it forwards or returns calls to the target instance. This is how e.g. transactions and security are implemented in the container.

As for the added question: Yes, the application server creates those proxy classes when necessary.

Comment: Martin. I was thinking about your answer and the possible implementation of creating proxy classes at runtime. I came up with this idea of how it could work. Say I have a test class. What the application server does is using Java reflection api it extends the test class and iterates through each of its operations overriding them adding for instance: begin() and end() transactions calls before and after calling the superclass method and then return a reference to this child class, is this correct?

Comment: Yes, this is essentially what's happening. Of course, there are different technical ways to implement proxies. A very simple yet powerful approach is using the DynamicProxy class from the standard library if you'd like to play with this technique yourself. Other methods are bytecode enhancement and aspect oriented programming (which relies on bytecode enhancement in most cases).